# Why Url.Content() not working in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

When I use this markup:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/damvomom.png" alt="header" width="100" height="100" />
```

the image is displayed.

But when I change to this:

```
<img scr="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/damvomom.png")" alt="Images" width="100" height="100" />
```

it doesn't display the image. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Check the rendered html. It should give you a hint of what's going on and how to fix the path.

Comment: I checked it, the scr in img tag that contain Url.Content() just display a string (/Content/Images/damvomom.png) not an Url

Comment: `scr` as `src` typo?

Answer (score 1):

Typo:  `scr=`. Should be `src=` instead.